# Problems with Jupyter labextensions in installing Jupyter Widgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble installing Jupyter Widgets for the Jupyter notebook. I've been following the instructions from here: http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html but have stumbled at the JupyterLab extension step (3rd line of code below):

```
pip install ipywidgets
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

The error message is:

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'labextensions': [Errno 'jupyter-     labextensions' not found] 2
```

As required above I've installed nodejs and it's added to my system PATH. Running the command line as an administrator and:

```
C:\Python\Scripts> jupyter labextension list
```

gives the same error message as above. However, the Jupyterlab website mentions:

> The base JupyterLab application comes with core set of extensions, which 
>   provide the Notebook, Terminal, Text Editor, etc

So given that I already launch Jupyter notebook with ...

```
C:\Python\Scripts> jupyter notebook
```

... shouldn't labextensions be installed already? Perhaps I'm not calling it from the right directory? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

PS: conda is not an option for me at the moment because it runs foul of my anti-virus

Comment: Are you trying to run JupyterLab or the classic Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Classic Jupyter Notebook but as mentioned in OP I was having some anti-virus related issues with conda at that time. This has been resolved and so I was able to download Jupyter Widgets via conda. Thanks